# Nothing happens on clicking social icons on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website, weebly

I created some social media icons on my website. My links are working fine on the desktop but nothing happens on tapping them in a mobile browser. Here is the website https://theopenbay.weebly.com and here is the code —

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.fa {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-telegram {
  background: #30a2e7;
  color: white;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Add font awesome icons -->
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/TheOpenBay" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="https://t.me/TheOpenBay" target="_blank" class="fa fa-telegram"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing `display: block` to `display: table` which reduced the navmobile height.

Context: the images posted by Iliass Nassibane above.

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to SO. I found the issue. The icons were blocked by the "navmobile" element. It covered the icons, so it wasn't possible to "press" the icons.

[image]

This was caused by the display block styling of that element. So by removing that you'll be able to make those icons clickable again.

[image]

Comment: Glad you find the problem! However, the nav content is also removing when I remove the display block styling. See this https://imgur.com/quZnDXp

Comment: Hi, maybe you could make the nav display:block only when active. that way it doesn't block further interaction on your app.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, I solved it by changing display: block to display: table which reduced the navmobile height.

Comment: Great job, bud!

Answer (score 0):

your problem is, that div#navmobile is overlaping your footer, #navmobile has z-index:8, what you can do, is that you can change div#my-footer's position to relative and z-index higher than 8, here is the code (you should add to css):

```
#my-footer{position:relative; z-index:99}
```

Comment: use that stile on div with these classes instead: <div class="wsite-elements wsite-not-footer"> </div>

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, I solved it by changing display: block to display: table which reduced the navmobile height.